# In MATLAB, how do I change the background color of a subplot?

Tags: matlab, plot, background-color

I'm trying to change the background color of a single subplot in a MATLAB figure.

It's clearly feasible since the UI allows it, but I cannot find the function to automate it.

I've looked into `whitebg`, but it changes the color scheme of the whole figure, not just the current subplot.

(I'm using MATLAB Version 6.1 by the way)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the set command.

```
set(subplot(2,2,1),'Color','Red')
```

That will give you a red background in the subplot location 2,2,1.

Comment: alternatively: ha=subplot(221); set(ha,'color','r');

Answer (score 4):

I know you mentioned that you are using MATLAB 6.1, but it bears mentioning that in the newer versions of MATLAB you can specify additional property-value pair arguments in the initial call to [SUBPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html), allowing for a more compact syntax. The following creates an axes with a red background in the top left corner of a 2-by-2 layout:

```
subplot(2,2,1,'Color','r');
```

I'm not certain in which version of MATLAB this syntax was introduced, since the [release notes going back to Version 7 (R14)](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/rn_intro.html) don't seem to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used Matlab in several years, but I think it might well be the whitebg method called after the subplot declaration, similar to the way in which you would set a title.

```
subplot(3, 2, 4), hist(rand(50)), whitebg('y');
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, that was my first guess but it changes the whole figure.